# olap4j connection to Analysis Service

Tags: ssas, olap4j

hi i am trying to connect to microsoft analysis service through olap4j but i got this error every time "org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query"

This Full Description of Error :

```
<code>22:30:45.331 [ERROR] [kimo] 22:30:45.326:XRP4:WARN:RPCManager:org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.undefined - response: {operationId: &quot;listCubes_fetch&quot;,
clientContext: Obj,
context: Obj,
transactionNum: 0,
httpResponseCode: 200,
httpResponseText: &quot;//isc_RPCResponseStart--&gt;[{data:&quot;org.ola...&quot;[212],
xmlHttpRequest: [object XMLHttpRequest],
transport: &quot;xmlHttpRequest&quot;,
status: -1,
clientOnly: undef,
httpHeaders: Obj,
isStructured: true,
callbackArgs: null,
results: Obj,
data: &quot;org.olap4j.OlapException: This connectio...&quot;[91],
invalidateCache: false,
isDSResponse: true,
queueStatus: -1,
startRow: 0,
endRow: 0,
totalRows: 0}

com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 22:30:45.326:XRP4:WARN:RPCManager:org.olap4j.OlapException: This connection encountered an exception while executing a query.undefined - response: {operationId: &quot;listCubes_fetch&quot;,
clientContext: Obj,
context: Obj,
transactionNum: 0,
httpResponseCode: 200,
httpResponseText: &quot;//isc_RPCResponseStart--&gt;[{data:&quot;org.ola...&quot;[212],
xmlHttpRequest: [object XMLHttpRequest],
transport: &quot;xmlHttpRequest&quot;,
status: -1,
clientOnly: undef,
httpHeaders: Obj,
isStructured: true,
callbackArgs: null,
results: Obj,
data: &quot;org.olap4j.OlapException: This connectio...&quot;[91],
invalidateCache: false,
isDSResponse: true,
queueStatus: -1,
startRow: 0,
endRow: 0,
totalRows: 0}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)



this is the connection function 

<code>

    public static OlapConnection getConnectionAServices() throws Exception {
            Class.forName("org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver");
            // anonymous connection
             Connection connectionXMLA =    DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:xmla:Server=http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll;" + "Catalog=Analysis_Service;");

            OlapWrapper wrapper = (OlapWrapper) connectionXMLA;
            OlapConnection olapConnection = wrapper.unwrap(OlapConnection.class);
            return olapConnection;
```

}

Comment: hello? anybody there? :)

Comment: You must provide more details. Stack traces. Logs. Anything you have would help. Just posting the general error message is not enough for us to help you out.

Comment: @Luc i added the full description of error ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set up XML/A HTTP access for SQL Server Analysis Services in IIS?

[Configuring HTTP Access to SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services on Microsoft Windows Server 2008](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx)

You also need to add a role in the database with appropriate permissions, and to add
the user you are running the application as to that role.